# SOAP Example On JBOSS server

Tags: soap

I'm trying to deploy this exemple using Soap web Service on a JBOSS,
I've the error that the page is not found when I try to access the URL (http://localhost:80/ServiceHelloWS)

Interface ServiceHelloWS :

```
package com.service.ws;

public interface ServiceHelloWS {

    public String sayHello();
}
```

Implementation :

```
package com.service.ws;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
@Stateless
public class ServiceHelloWSImpl implements ServiceHelloWS{

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Publishing Class:

```
package com.service.pub;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import com.service.ws.*;

public class SoapWSpub {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:80/ServiceHelloWS", new ServiceHelloWSImpl());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are hitting the url the main method is not getting invoked. This is the reason why you are getting page not found. The solution is to define the SOAP API as a service not in the main method but inside some controller class.

Comment: I don't need the publishing class?

Comment: If you want to generate the wsdl file then you need to execute the Endpoint.publish statement. So you please shift that statement to an appropriate file e.g a servlet and not the main method since JBoss is an application server and it will not execute the standalone main method.